# JAVA - How to make custom holidays and keep track of them

Tags: java, calendar

Making a Calendar that allows you to add in specific holidays

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.  Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I could not more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Date` class if you can possibly avoid it.  You should instead consider `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: @AshCochrane. Check my answer as to why your approach is not working

Comment: @JoeC The question is not clear at all for me. It could also be a question about how to construct an UI-calendar with columns and rows displaying holidays instead of just using the API of `java.util.Calendar`. The OP should clarify his question.

Comment: I liked the previous version of your question better where you had shown the code you had. Even if an answer recommends a complete rewrite, your code is still illustrative of what more precisely you are trying, and showing an effort always makes other users more forthcoming.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `java.time` package. Specifically the `MonthDay` class to represent a holiday, as holidays are usually some fixed month + day (however you will need more complicated logic than a `Set<MonthDay>` if the holidays are "dynamic").

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.MonthDay;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CustomHolidays {
    private final Set<MonthDay> holidays = new HashSet<>();

    public void addHoliday(final MonthDay monthDay) {
        holidays.add(monthDay);
    }

    public boolean isHoliday(final LocalDate localDate) {
        return isWeekend(localDate) || holidays.contains(toMonthDay(localDate));
    }

    public int numberOfWorkdaysBetween(final LocalDate startInclusive, final LocalDate endInclusive) {
        int c = 0;
        for (LocalDate i = startInclusive; !i.isAfter(endInclusive); i = i.plusDays(1)) {
            if (!isHoliday(i)) {
                c++;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    private boolean isWeekend(final LocalDate localDate) {
        final DayOfWeek dow = localDate.getDayOfWeek();
        return dow == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || dow == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
    }

    private static MonthDay toMonthDay(final LocalDate localDate) {
        return MonthDay.of(localDate.getMonth(), localDate.getDayOfMonth());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final CustomHolidays ch = new CustomHolidays();
        ch.addHoliday(MonthDay.of(Month.MAY, 1));
        ch.addHoliday(MonthDay.of(Month.MAY, 2));
        ch.addHoliday(MonthDay.of(Month.MAY, 3));

        System.out.println(ch.numberOfWorkdaysBetween(LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 1), LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 8)));
    }
}
```

Output: `3`

Comment: Use a loop like in the `numberOfWorkdaysBetween` method, of course.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by others, you should go ahead and use `java.time.LocalDate` instead.

But if you are still curious as to why your current approach is not working, read ahead.

**1st Problem:** The following while condition will stop once the day is equal, even if months are different (because `dayIndex!= yDay` will evaluate to `false`)

```
while (monthIndex != yMonth && dayIndex != yDay)
```

Changing the while condition to below one will check for both the day and month. Also compare `monthIndex` to `yMonth-1` since your `monthIndex` is initialised as `xMonth-1`

```
while (!(monthIndex == yMonth-1 && dayIndex == yDay))
```

**2nd problem:** Change `int calMonth = xMonth;` to `int calMonth = xMonth-1`; for the same reason as mentioned in problem 1.

**3rd Problem:** Initialise `dayIndex` to `0` instead of `1`, because you are incrementing `dayIndex` after the `if` block. If you initialise it to `1`, it will increment to `2` and hence 1st date of every month will be skipped.

```
        if (dayIndex == numDaysInMonth+1) {
            dayIndex = 0;
            monthIndex++;
        }
        dayIndex++;
```

Check [here](http://tpcg.io/jOXHsX) for working fiddle